# Captcha Failed on Custom Validation

Tags: 7, forms, captcha

I use the following validation handler on the login form.

```php
function wemusic_user_login_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $username = $form['name']['#value'];
  if ($user = user_load_by_name($username)) {
    if ($user->status == "1") {
      $form_state = array();
      $form_state['uid'] = $user->uid;
      user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
    }
    else {
      drupal_goto('registration/confirm', array('query'=>array('user' => $username)));
    }
  }
  else {
    drupal_goto('user/register');
  }
}
```

How can I call the CAPTCHA validation in my validation handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a improved version of your code

```
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'wemusic_user_login_validate';
        $form['#submit'] = array();
        array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'wemusic_user_login_submit');
    }

function wemusic_user_login_validate($form, &$form_state){
    $username = $form['name']['#value'];
    $user = user_load_by_name($username);
    if ($user && $user->status != "1"){
            drupal_set_message("Baba Taid kon bad boro to",'error');
            drupal_goto('registration/confirm', array('query'=>array(
                'user'=>$username,
            )));
    }
   else {
        drupal_set_message("Sabenam nakarde mikhay beri to akhe amo ?!!!",'error');
        drupal_goto('user/register');
    }
}
```

*When you are in user_login and user is going to login don't empty $form_state  with $form_state = array();* Let Drupal Handle it's way to log on user  you just check what you want before it.

This will work for you , but I think is better when the situation is not satisfied in validator set error and set a destination variable on $form_state  ( maybe $form_state['redirect'] or your custom $form_state['my_redirect'] )  then in form_alter  check if  your error exists redirect to that destination with Drupal_goto.

Any way mentioned code ( up code) satisfy what you want.